# Does having a bad table and column naming convention is a good protection against Sql injection

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

An hacker have much more chance to try to inject this query:

```
') DELETE FROM Users --
```

then this one:

```
') DELETE From Blargblarbglbglab--
```

Does having a bad table and column naming convention is a good additional protection against Sql injection.

Comment: Good coding practices and testing is a good protection against SQL injection.

Comment: If  your site is vulnerable to SQL injection then it's trivial to get a list of the tables in your DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a good technique / tactic, aside from making your own life very difficult - if you have a vulnrability that allows them to query tables and see the results in some form, they can inject a query to look in the information_schema views / tables.

So the bad naming only get's in your own way, it doesn't make it impossible for a hacker to find out the table names.

Protect against it properly with the right coding practises.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article and it explains how to prevent SQL Injection attacks quite nicely :o)

[MySQL - SQL Injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

If a hacker has managed to attack your site, they'll be able to access the system tables so it doesn't really matter what or how you name tables/columns.  It is best to try and avoid SQL injection hacks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this may stop a good hacker. Over the net you can find many better solutions for your query. If you don't have any experience, in the [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) there is a suitable description and lots of links.

Answer (score 2):

For a **proper** protection against SQL injection, you need to make sure the "hacker" cannot execute any database query of his own.

Answer (score 2):

you should not name variables on querystring equal to columns on DB in order to do not give sensitive data to everybody. Apart from this, **always sanitize** your inputs

Comment: the same applies to html in general: in particular the name of input fields, the ID of columns grids, etc, this are the places where the same name is the "simplest" but not a good choise

Answer (score 1):

Your users should never be able to execute any queries, and bad table names should therefore only confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: technically yes, but it is a bad idea. Technically, a shovel full of dirt can stem the flood, but it will still destroy you in the end. Long answer: You always have to escape your data. ***ALWAYS***. No exceptions, ***EVER***.

Funny table names will only hurt your development time and increase your technical debt far more than any benefit this could possibly have. It *will* cost you time and it *probably will* lead to an increase in the number of bugs as it **definitely** is harder to remember.